# SQL Server 2012 - Know when a SEQUENCE has recycled or is nearing cycle phase

Tags: sql-server, sequence

In SQL Server 2012, is there a way to know if a `Sequence` has recycled?

Or some sort of trigger to know if a `Sequence` is nearing its cycling phase.

I need to update a table whenever a `Sequence`recycles.

Answer (score 0):

There is no metadata view that is going to clearly give you this information. Your best bet would be to have a scheduled process that runs every few minutes and looks at `sys.sequences` and evaluates if the `current_value` is less than the prior `current_value`, in which case you would know that it had cycled.

You can also compare the `current_value` to the `maximum_value` to see how close you are to hitting the cycle point.

A very basic view of this would be the following with a small sequence, you can see the initial values remaining, what it looks like after using a few sequences, and then how it gets reset as the sequence cycles.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.TestSeq 
AS SMALLINT
MINVALUE 1
MAXVALUE 10
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
CYCLE;

SELECT  name ,
        current_value ,
        maximum_value ,
        CAST(maximum_value AS BIGINT) - CAST(current_value AS BIGINT) AS Values_Remaining
FROM    sys.sequences
WHERE   name = 'TestSeq';
GO

SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.TestSeq;
GO 5

SELECT  name ,
        current_value ,
        maximum_value ,
        CAST(maximum_value AS BIGINT) - CAST(current_value AS BIGINT) AS Values_Remaining
FROM    sys.sequences
WHERE   name = 'TestSeq';
GO

SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.TestSeq;
GO 6

SELECT  name ,
        current_value ,
        maximum_value ,
        CAST(maximum_value AS BIGINT) - CAST(current_value AS BIGINT) AS Values_Remaining
FROM    sys.sequences
WHERE   name = 'TestSeq';
GO
```